# Azure YAML pipeline: dynamically name a task

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

Our Azure YAML pipeline uses the same task (from a template) multiple times, but right now the `name` field is a static string. This results in an error, because the name of a task must be unique. My plan is to dynamically name the field instead. However, so far my attempts have failed. Below is the code sniplet:

```
parameters:
  - name: dynamicalNamePart
    type: string
  - name: someOtherParameter
    type: string

steps:
  - task: theTask@1
    name: theTask_${{ parameters.dynamicalNamePart }}
    displayName: 'Failing task'
    inputs:
      secureFile: ${{ parameters.dynamicalNamePart }}

  - task: taskWithScript@1
    inputs:
      inputA: someInputA
      inputB: someInputB
    inlineScript: |
      echo $(someEnvVariable)
      someCommand someOption $(theTask_${{ dynamicalNamePart }}.somePropertyOfTheTask)
```

Is the idea that I have in mind possible? And if so, which changes would I need to make to this script?

One additional question: I am having a hard time testing my changes, is there any extension or website where I can validate my syntax?

Edit 1: on further investigation I found out that parameter `dynamicalNamePart` is also a reference from the main pipeline file. Instead of getting the value of this parameter, I receive `$(someVariableFromMainPipeline)`.

Comment: This can work, but only if dynamicalNamePart is a value known at compile-time; e.g. a parameter, or a hard-coded variable. The task names need to be unique when the pipeline is compiled (i.e. when you queue it up), so you can't rely on variables which only get their value at runtime.

Comment: @VinceBowdren This is indeed the issue that I was dealing with. The `dynamicNamePart` is not known at compile-time, and as a consequence the following would literally be passed: $(name-of-passed-variable). This string contains the characters `$`, `(`, and `)`  which are all not allowed as a task name. I instead resolve the issue by adding a hard-coded parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be that parameter `dynamicalNamePart` was unknown at compile-time. As a consequence, the variable name would be used as such: `$(someVariableNamePassedToTemplate)`. As this string contains several characters that are not allowed to be included in a task name (`$`, `(`, and `)`), the pipeline would not run. Instead, I provided a hard-coded parameter which nicely did the job.

In addition, I used to [Azure Pipelines YAML Validator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TomAustin.azure-devops-yaml-pipeline-validator) extension for Visual Studio Code to check my syntax. Works pretty nicely! Just keep in mind that the extension sends the YAML code to a remote server for validation, which may be an issue for some people.